# Local variable 'links' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

The Scrapy parsing method I have implemented gives me the error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'links' referenced before assignment

Being fairly new to scrapy I have very less idea about what I'm doing wrong here. I wanted to have scope for new websites that I will add in future but how do I implement the xpath particular to that website so that it scrapes its inner links?

The xpaths are correct and work in shell.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from rvcalinkscrapper.items import RvcalinkscrapperItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose
from w3lib.html import remove_tags

class MultifileoutSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'multifileout'
allowed_domains = []
start_urls = []
read_urls = open('../urls.txt', 'r')
for url in read_urls.readlines():
    url = url.strip() 
    allowed_domains = allowed_domains + [url[4:]]
    start_urls = start_urls + ['http://' + url]
read_urls.close()

def parse(self, response):

    item_loader = ItemLoader(item=RvcalinkscrapperItem(), response=response)
    item_loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(remove_tags)
    item_loader.default_output_processor = TakeFirst()

    shop = response.xpath("shop")
    if shop == "shop0":
        links = '//li[@class="mobile-nav__item"]/a/@href'
    elif shop == "shop1":
        links = '//ul[@class="level2 unstyled"]/li/a/@href'

    item_loader.add_xpath("links", links)

    item_loader.add_value("shop", shop)

    item_loader.add_value("url", response.url)

    return item_loader.load_item()
```

Comment: If `shop` is neither `"shop0"` nor `"shop1"`, the variable `links` is not initialized. In either case, you should either give it a default value or not use it.

Comment: @DyZ could you probably write that in answer with a working patch of code?

Comment: But look at @BruceWayne's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If `shop` is not one of those two things, `links` is not assigned.  You could just do

```
...
links = '//li[@class="mobile-nav__item"]/a/@href'
shop = response.xpath("shop")
if shop == "shop1":
    links = '//ul[@class="level2 unstyled"]/li/a/@href'
...
```

Assuming there's a "default" path you want to use (I used `shop0`'s). Obviously you can switch this up, or add an `elif` to it.

Comment: the same error persists. this is what i did.        `shop = response.xpath("shop")
       if shop == "shop0":
            links = '//li[@class="mobile-nav__item"]/a/@href'

        shop = response.xpath("shop")

        if shop == "shop1":
            links = '//ul[@class="level2 unstyled"]/li/a/@href'

        item_loader.add_xpath("links", links)`

Comment: @anshumananand - and you're *positive* that the `shop = ...` will return only `shop1` or `shop0`? Not, say `shop3`, `no1`, etc?

Comment: when new websites will be added then i will definately need to add one more xpath using shop3 so it has to return shop3 also.

Comment: @anshumananand but currently are you positive that `links` will be one of those two paths? What if it's *not*, what do you want to return for `links`?